# Unity 4.6: sprite image automatically splits to single sprites when clicking

Tags: unity

I'm viewing Unity tutorial. As in this tutorial, I see when author clicks to sprite image, they will automatically divide to each frame as below:

[image]

But in my Unity, I just can view this:
[image]

So. My question is: How can my sprite image automatically divides to each sprite.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not aware that this is possible just by clicking on the sprite sheet without setting the separate sprites in the sprite editor... Maybe it was some Kung fu editing that was done to the video instead of an actual unity feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the import settings (click on the spritesheet in the project view and look at the inspector) so they import as multiple sprites. Then from the sprite editor you choose options to automatically split the spritesheet by putting in the dimensions of each sprite in the sheet this will cause the sprites to be split like you see in the tutorial

Unfortunately I don't know if you can alter the default import settings for sprites so that all sheets are split when put into the project directory by predefined parameters although I personally have never seen this happen.

Edit: I found this unity answers question that relates to automatically importing sprites, one of the answers mentions a plugin which will automatically split spritesheets:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/793730/how-to-set-default-sprite-import-settings.html